# Atlassian stash equivalent git manager (opensource)

Tags: java, git, repository, bitbucket-server

I have used Atlassian stash for git repository management. I want to know is there any open-source git manager which could fulfill the following needs:

1. Browsing the code base?
2. Code reviews with pull request ?

Thanks

~Sohil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Update]** 
While I haven't used it yet [GitLab](https://about.gitlab.com/features/) is looking promising. I believe that gitorious was bought out by GitLab. The free version is still missing things like LDAP support.

**[Original]** 
gitorious + gerrit 
or 
gitolite  + gerrit + git-web

If you're in the enterprise world - the open source options are lacking unless you have a dedicated scm manager or a small team. gitolite is very powerful, but doing things like managing users can be difficult.